# Get full expanded menu?

Tags: 7, routes

How can I render out my main menu as entirely expanded? I am working on mobile navigation and need to have the entire tree rendered out in my code for this to work the way I want it to. I do not want to make admins go into the menu and select "expanded" every time they create a child item. Can this be done with a module or

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think [menu_tree_all_data](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/includes!menu.inc/function/menu_tree_all_data/7) should do the trick.

You will need to put this in a custom module and then loop over the array to manually build your menu.